# "Unzip" items so I can use them

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I received some of these items from another player and some from the event quests.

[image]

They came in this weird format to save some space, I think. How can I "unzip" them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are bank [notes](https://runescape.wiki/w/Note). As you guessed, they can stack higher than the item can without taking multiple spaces in your inventory.
You can exchange them for the items that they represent at any bank.

The other items you have are [sets](https://runescape.wiki/w/Item_set). These function similarly to the bank note.
However, these need to be exchanged by a Grand Exchange Clerk.

Comment: Two of those items are  bank notes, the others are sets, which work differently.

Comment: @TimmyJim How can I unzip the sets too then?

Comment: @msm.oliveira see my answer.

Comment: Didn't even see the sets! Answer updated to include both.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is 6 [item sets](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Item_set), and 2 noted items.  To get the individual items in the set, you must speak to a Grand Exchange clerk at the Grand Exchange in Varrock (north of the west bank).  They will have a right click option called "exchange."  Using this option, you can get the indivudal items.  As for the bank notes, just place them in your bank and withdraw them again.

Comment: I believe you can also use noted items on a banker, and they will unote them provided you have the inventory space.